# RPG IV Files processing issue

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

I am still learning RPG and AS/400. coming from MS C#.NET.
we are currently moving to iSeries machine and I am trying to pickup  the IBM RPG and CL programming as it is more needed for the company.

the iSeries version if I am reading it right is
dspdtaara QSS1MRI:  ==> "V7R1M000    2924"

DSPSFWRSC+ F11 : ==>

```
 5770999   *BASE    5050     *CODE   QSYS        V7R1M0 L00 
 5770SS1   *BASE    5050     *CODE   QSYS        V7R1M0 L00 
 5770SS1   *BASE    2924     *LNG    QSYS        V7R1M0 L00    
 ... 
 5770WDS   56       5101     *CODE   QDEVTOOLS   V7R1M0  
 5770WDS   60       5050     *CODE   QDEVTOOLS   V7R1M0
```

here is my issue.

I have a flat file that is generated on the old AS400 machine and is copied to the new iSeries
file is a delimited data  (using ";" )  that I need to reformat and export to FTP for further processing by outside company. each record have either 29 or 28 columns. thus first thing I do is using an SQLRPGLE program add an extra delimiter to the records that are missing one. in the flat file itself

```
 C/EXEC SQL 
 C+ SELECT  
 C+   MAX((length(trim(F00001))- length(REPLACE(trim(F00001),';',''))))
 C+ , MIN((length(trim(F00001))- length(REPLACE(trim(F00001),';',''))))
 C+ INTO :MaxCount, :@DelimCount 
 C+ FROM QGPL.fIncomming  
 C/END-EXEC        

  **/*  using the delimiter could fix data by inserting a delimiter in the proper place */

 C/EXEC SQL  
 C+ UPDATE QGPL.fIncomming
 C+  SET F00001 = INSERT(F00001,225,0,';') 
 C+ WHERE ( :MaxCount
 C+         - (  length(trim(F00001))  
 C+            - length(REPLACE(trim(F00001),';','')) )
 C+       ) > 0 
 C/END-EXEC
```

then I created 2 tables (PF) on iSeries

Table1, which is an SQL table with 29 columns based on the incoming file format, (All columns are named and set to length of the data, but all columns are text (A) type )

and the second table (Table2)  which have exactly the same layout as table (Table1) but each columns is of specific data type as needed. 
i.e. id is INTEGER and dateof is DATE etc.

no the data is not clean. thus a date field might have spaces in it or money field might have text in it.

I need the best way to move the data to table2 cleaning up and validating it during the transfer.
the SQL way would be the best but the statement is so big I can not truly validate it properly.

can some one suggest (with an example if possible) other ways or better way to write SQL for it
I basically have this but get a lot of errors: and if I try to run it in STRSQL not all the code fits in a screen.

```
SELECT
 TRIM(ORDERID) as ORDERID
...,LINENUM) <> ''
      THEN TRIM(LINENUM) 
      ELSE 9999 END as LINENUM
, TRIM(CUSTNUM) as CUSTNUM
, TRIM(PONUM) as PONUM
, CASE WHEN TRIM(REPLACE(ORDDATE,0,'')) <> ''
       THEN CAST(INSERT(INSERT(ORDDATE,5,0,'/'),3,0,'/') as Date) 
...
from Table1
```

AS REQUESTED:
This is the original flat file data [preceded first by column headings c1-c29 for records with 29 effective columns of delimited data, then second by column headings c1-c28 with a `*Err->` pointing out where the expected delimiter and 30 blanks are missing for the secondary records *because each record should share the **same** layout*, and third by an embedded ruler-line to show the 225th position where the semicolon would be added with the prior SQL code *and optionally 30 blanks could be added to effect maintaining the fixed-length layout*.]:

```
---c1----c2---c3----c4---------c5-------c6-------c7-------c8----------c9-----------c10-------c11--------------c12--------------c13----c14-c15---c16---c17---c18------c19---------c20------c21-----c22-------------c23-----------------------c24------------------c25----c26----c27------c28-----c29---
---c1----c2---c3----c4---------c5-------c6-------c7-------c8----------c9-----------c10-------c11--------------c12--------------c13----c14-c15---c16---c17---c18------c19---------c20------c21-----c22-------------c23-----*ERR->---c24--c25----c26-------c27-----c28-- **missing one column!**
....+....1....+....2....+....3....+....4....+....5....+....6....+....7....+....8....+....9....+...10....+...11....+...12....+...13....+...14....+...15....+...16....+...17....+...18....+...19....+...20....+...21....+...22....+...23....+...24....+...25....+...26....+...27....+...28....+...29....+
1596555;001;10010;TEST5     ;01062015; 1213.00; 1219.00;  17.000;NET 30 DAYS ;            ;543534241;TOYYO1/5                ;  14OZ  ;T; 5.00; .500;   1; 560.00;          ;   560.00;01292015;5379602;** 2ND DAY **           ;5XDFSDFFGFGHGHGH16            ;      ;   ;          ;        ; 
1596555;   ;10010;          ;        ;        ;        ;        ;            ;            ;         ;                        ;        ; ;     ; .   ;    ;       ;          ;         ;01292015;5379602;                        ; 16.60;FRT;          ;        ; 
1598556;001;10021;TEST      ;02112015; 1237.00; 1207.00;  17.000;NET 30 DAYS ;            ;567860502;45GGH/4019              ;  10OZ  ;R;12.50; .000;   1; 105.42;          ;   105.42;02122015;5380313;** 2ND DAY **           ;3HGFH5456GFHFG5G27            ;      ;   ;          ;        ;
1598556;   ;10021;          ;        ;        ;        ;        ;            ;            ;         ;                        ;        ; ;     ; .   ;    ;       ;          ;         ;02122015;5380313;                        ; 13.19;FRT;          ;        ; 
1598557;001;10067;020415    ;02042015; 1283.00; 1238.00;  18.000;NET 30 DAYS ;            ;657870142;FTKG061/11              ;  14OZ  ;R;     ; .330;   1; 358.00;          ;   358.00;02092015;5380071;** 2ND DAY **           ;3NHJYJ64646GHJGHJ8            ;      ;   ;          ;        ;
1598557;   ;10067;          ;        ;        ;        ;        ;            ;            ;         ;                        ;        ; ;     ; .   ;    ;       ;          ;         ;02092015;5380071;                        ; 15.09;FRT;          ;        ;
```

And this is the desired outcome that is currently generate by MS SQL process [preceded by an embedded ruler-line]:

```
....+....1....+....2....+....3....+....4....+....5....+....6....+....7....+....8....+....9....+...10....+...11....+...12....+...13....+...14....+...15....+...16....+...17....+...18....+...19....+...20....+...21....+
"1596555",1,"10010","TEST5",01/06/2015, 1213.00, 1219.00, 17.00,"NET 30 DAYS",,"543534241","TOYYO1/5","14OZ","T",5.00,0.50,1, 560.00,, 560.00,01/29/2015,"5379602","** 2ND DAY **","5XDFSDFFGFGHGHGH16",,,,,
"1596555",9999,"10010",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,01/29/2015,"5379602",,,"16.60","FRT",,,
"1598556",1,"10021","TEST",02/11/2015, 1237.00, 1207.00, 17.00,"NET 30 DAYS",,"567860502","45GGH/4019","10OZ","R",12.50,0.00,1, 105.42,, 105.42,02/12/2015,"5380313","** 2ND DAY **","3HGFH5456GFHFG5G27",,,,,
"1598556",9999,"10021",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,02/12/2015,"5380313",,,"13.19","FRT",,,
"1598557",1,"10067","020415",02/04/2015, 1283.00, 1238.00, 18.00,"NET 30 DAYS",,"657870142","FTKG061/11","14OZ","R",,0.33,1, 358.00,, 358.00,02/09/2015,"5380071","** 2ND DAY **","3NHJYJ64646GHJGHJ8",,,,,
"1598557",9999,"10067",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,02/09/2015,"5380071",,,"15.09","FRT",,,
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a few representative file rows? Also, please include the OS version/release so we know what functions might be available.

Comment: sure  user2338816, however my formatting go all over the place when I post. not sure why though. could it be because I am suing fire fox?

Comment: These look like variable length records, how do you know the missing delimiter always goes at position 225?

Comment: sorry I forgot to indicate the issue more clearly.

Comment: it always missing delimiter on pos 225 for records with freight information. those are the mostly empty lines with FRT in column 26. for some reason this records merge the columns for ship type and ups tracking code when generated

Comment: Did you consider using an ETL (see Kettle, Talend in their free version... or even DataCleaner ) ? Works perfectly for this kind of task with IBM i (with jdbc driver jt400.jar), worth the investment if you have more job like this. In pure SQL you will quickly run into unmaintainable code.

Comment: If the formats are consistent, I see zero problems using nothing but SQL and CPYFRMIMPF and CPYTOIMPF. It certainly wouldn't be unmaintainable... assuming consistent formats. It's a little hard to be sure because I can't be sure where records begin and end. It **looks like** there are three example FRT records, though they're not frmatted well. (I use Firefox and have no problems posting lines or source code. here.)

Comment: ohh I see, the data is garbled up in the post. all end of records have been removed. there is not 3 examples of FRT records but 3 sets of 2 records per account. the first columns always an account number and can have multiple lines per account, but the last line is always FRT record line. I choosed accounts with only 2 lines per record-set to make it simple. and like I said the FRT line always matches the main record line with exception of missing delimiter at position 225 where it should be splitting ship type and ups tracking number columns all other columns are there and accounted for.

Comment: Ah! That makes more sense. I submitted an edit to see if it helps us all understand. It looks to me as if this can be done in a few fairly direct steps and possibly no programming at all except for a CL to run the steps and maybe a couple small SQL scripts. If a couple work tables are created, the rest would be fairly easy.

Comment: Ok not an answer but I managed to build out an RPGLE program that reads the incoming file, splits the record into columns as needed (since all files is pretty much a fixed lenght as it's comes out it was easy ) and inserts into target table putting Nulls in the fields when incoming data is empty.  than the normal process (the CL I have build before) takes over and exports the table to CSV as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would read the FIncomming directly into the RPG program, and not worry about that missing delimiter. I am guessing it is at the end of the record anyway (you didn't really tell us that). Parse out the fileds as you would in C/C++, the standard C library is available to RPGIV. For each record validate the fields, and if all are valid, write directly to Table 2 mentioned in your question. Records with errors would be written to Table 1 for remediation.

Now you mention that the data needs to be FTP'd to an outside company, that is another issue altogether. Scott Klement has an API that you can use to FTP files directly from within RPG. His web site is http://www.scottklement.com.

And one more thing, given that you are new to RPG, you might want to learn free format rather than the fixed format variant as that is the modern way to code RPG. That SQL statement in free format would look like:

```
  exec sql  
    UPDATE qgpl.fIncomming
      SET F00001 = INSERT(F00001,225,0,';')
      WHERE :MaxCount - length(trim(F00001) - length(REPLACE(trim(F00001),';',''))) > 0;
```

There are many ways to generate a comma seperated file from a database file. The easiest is to use CL command CPYTOIMPF, prompt it, and you can see the options. That command can also drop the file directly into the IFS with translation to ASCII for transfer to MS-SQL.

---

**Edit March 3, 2017**

Wow, looks like some folks are using some really old stuff. So if you are on a release of i5/OS, or OS/400 prior to V5R4, the code looks like this

```
c/exec sql  
c+  UPDATE qgpl.fIncomming
c+    SET F00001 = INSERT(F00001,225,0,';')
c+    WHERE :MaxCount - length(trim(F00001) - length(REPLACE(trim(F00001),';',''))) > 0;
c/end-exec
```

This is fixed format, notice the `c` spec. If you are coding in free format on this old release, and need the SQL precompiler to understand what you are doing, you will need to add `/end-free` and `/free` compiler directives around the fixed form portions of your code. @Dam included a link in the comments.

Comment: thanks jmarkmurphy, FTP is not an issue as I have that all working. 
in fact it have been working for almost a week until I noticed that data was not processing 
on FTP site. this was when I compared the original output file from MSSQL batch and the one 
I was generating on IBM and saw differences in formatting. 
I do not know C/C++ so can not really say how to parse things out in there. 
also the free format like you show me is not working for me, not sure why.
I use SQLRPGLE as source file type for my program.

Comment: With V7R1 you can do free form RPG, to follow @jmarkmurphy method, see an example here :  [link](http://www.bmeyers.net/faqs/15-faqs/75-embedded-sql-using-a-cursor)

Comment: You can use the free form method I showed starting with V5R4. Starting with v7.1 you can define H, F, D, and P specs in free format, and with the appropriate database group ptfs you can reference host variables defined with free format.

Comment: Next comment, if you are getting the data from an old AS400, why is it a flat file? why not just save it to a save file, then ftp the save file to the new iSeries? Make sure you use binary mode, but it should work fine. Have done that many times. Then you can just write SQL to map the old fields to the new fields if necessary.

Comment: the problem is that it probobly is  a save file already. we are in the process of migrating to new iSeries from an old AS/400+System36(or 38) emulator. all working stuff is originally in Sys36/38(not sure exact version as it have been upgraded before) the source file have been prepared and outputted from Sys36 originally and still is, almost 2 years ago. as we do the conversion the consultant we use moves the data to iSeries daily and use that file to output to local share drive forme to use with SQL. thus I want to use the source directly now.

Comment: If you are able to manipulate it with SQL, it is a database file,  not a savefile. A savefile has to be restored before the objects in it can be used.

Comment: I have used your advice for processing and simply went with RPG solutions mixed with SQL and CL apps. I created a output table based on file format, read each record in RPG into a DS using subst() to extract proper info and than write all into out file. than using CL app I generate the CSV and upload it via FTP to the server.  thanks.  P.S. it is a bit more work but it is less hastle to do it this way for now.

Comment: @Dam your link above added on Apr 10 '15 at 16:22 to bmeyers.net no longer works, is there another example of this?

Comment: @mike  Don't remember exactly what programming technique was in the link, but if it's about free form programming with SQL there's a good introduction here : [Embedding SQL in /free](https://www.itjungle.com/2005/03/02/fhg030205-story01/)

Comment: @Dam, that example embeds fixed form SQL in a free form program. If you are using free form, the way I showed above works. If it doesn't, you are either on an old release < v5r4, or you need a PTF.

Answer (score 2):

I am not authorized [yet] to "comment", so I am using the "answer" feature instead, to solicit more information :-(

  Regarding the statement in the OP that "*I created 2 tables (PF) on iSeries*", the SQL DDL for those two TABLE objects was not included.  Having that information would better allow reviewers of the scenario to propose some ideas, using the already-defined TABLEs, rather than the reviewer proposing something else that might possibly be unacceptable within the constraints mandated\established for the scenario; we can only presume that those two tables are a requirement, given the SELECT and UPDATE statements apparently reference those [yet to be described] tables.?

FWiW, when presenting an issue\scenario, offering all of the relevant details [as much as reasonably possible anyhow] is best, to elicit worthwhile feedback; otherwise a topic ends up receiving many *comments* asking for additional clarification of the scenario.  That appears to have transpired already with this topic.

Comment: Good to see you here, Chuck. With your background/knowledge, you'll have no problem quickly building enough rep for comments.